# Guarantee a final tick matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a figure with 7 subplots, looking like the one below, all with duration on the y-axis, but with different scales (picked by matplotlib). To improve readability, can I avoid the cut-off of my data points, by having at least one more axis tick? I don't want to exert manual control over the scaling.

[image: cut-off-datapoints]

The relevant source code for this plot is:

```
time_fig, time_axes = plt.subplots(2, 4, figsize=(18.0, 10.0))

for i, ax in enumerate(time_axes.flatten()[:-1]):    
    ax.plot_date(x=np.arange(1,4), y=timeframe.groupby('day').get_group(i+1)['runtime'], fmt='co' ,xdate=False, ydate=True)
    ax.set_ylim(bottom=datetime.date(1900,1,1), top=None)    
    ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(DateFormatter('%H:%M:%S'))        
    ax.set_xticks(np.arange(1,4))

plt.subplots_adjust(top=0.95, bottom=0.05, left=0.05, right=0.95, hspace=.30, wspace=0.30)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Usually this shouldn't happen. Each point would be visible with its complete circumference when using the default settings. Hence you apparently changed something. Yet, we don't know what it is because no code is shared in the question.

Comment: What I meant was of course a runnable code, see [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ylim`, see for instance [this example](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/step_demo.html#sphx-glr-gallery-lines-bars-and-markers-step-demo-py)

Comment: ylim is not really an option, because I can't predict what the scale should be.